# Workflow for reading and writing files

Tags: air

In [Workflow for reading and writing files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc8.html) the authors use these two lines of code:

```
var file = air.File.documentsDirectory; 
file = file.resolvePath("AIR Test/testFile.txt");
```

But I think that it's using one variable for two different meanings, isn't it?

Wouldn't it be better to write them as:

```
var myDocumentsDirectory = air.File.documentsDirectory; 
var myTestFile = myDocumentsDirectory.resolvePath("AIR Test/testFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right; however, if it were me, I'd just put it all on one line:

```
var myTestFile = air.File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("AIR Test/testFile.txt");
```